# Python: Using dictionary in place of if statements in a function that converts text numbers to digits

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically what I want to do is to use a dictionary in place of a lot of if statements in this function which converts numbers in text to digits (e.g. 'one two two five' to 1225):

```
def text_to_digit(s):
    temp = ''
    num = ''
    for i in s:
        if i == ' ':
            if temp == 'zero':
                num = num + '0'
            elif temp == 'one':
                num = num + '1'
            elif temp == 'two':
                num = num + '2'
            elif temp == 'three':
                num = num + '3'
            elif temp == 'four':
                num = num + '4'
            elif temp == 'five':
                num = num + '5'
            elif temp == 'six':
                num = num + '6'
            elif temp == 'seven':
                num = num + '7'
            elif temp == 'eight':
                num = num + '8'
            else:
                num = num + '9'
            temp = ''
        else:
            temp = temp + i

    # for the last number
    if temp == 'zero':
        num = num + '0'
    elif temp == 'one':
        num = num + '1'
    elif temp == 'two':
        num = num + '2'
    elif temp == 'three':
        num = num + '3'
    elif temp == 'four':
        num = num + '4'
    elif temp == 'five':
        num = num + '5'
    elif temp == 'six':
        num = num + '6'
    elif temp == 'seven':
        num = num + '7'
    elif temp == 'eight':
        num = num + '8'
    else:
        num = num + '9'

    # covert string to int
    return int(num)
```

What I came up with is something like this:

```
def text_to_digit(s):
    temp=''
    num=''
    d={'one':'1', 'two':'2', 'three':'3', 'four': '4', 'five':'5', 'six':'6', 'seven':'7', 'eight':'8', 'nine':'9', 'zero':'0'}
    for i in s:
        if i == '':
            num = num + d[temp]
            temp=''
        else: 
            temp = temp + i
        
    num=num+d[temp]
            
    return int(num)
```

However, it is not returning anything. I've tried to debug, and it seems the problem is with the if statement in the second function. At first space in the string, instead of doing num=num+d[temp], it went on to the else statement and did temp=temp+i.

Any ideas why this happened? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show a typical example of `s` - the input?

Comment: One example was in the first paragraph, 'one two two five' to 1225.

Comment: Wrong comparison in the if should be - `if i == ' ':`

Comment: you wrote `if i == '':` instead of `if i == ' ':`

Comment: This kind of thing is the reason debuggers exist - so you can step through the code line-by-line, watch it execute, and pinpoint where things go wrong. You really really should learn how to debug your own code, since it's an essential tool for any developer. You can't always rely on people on the internet to do your simple debugging for you. There's plenty of free tools out there for debugging, I highly recommend [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html)

Comment: @HenryWang - got the example and came with an answer. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: You're only looking up the empty string `''` which doesn't have any dictionary value.  Kind of like Major Major in Catch-22.

Comment: @balderman, technically that's not the answer he was looking for. You've only provided an alternate solution to the problem that he's trying to solve.

Comment: @navneethc I just came with a solution that does not involve unnecessary  variables.

Comment: Ah I get it now, stupid mistake. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

How about the below ? The idea is to split the input string and do a 'lookup' - join everything and convert to `int`

```
LOOKUP = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', 'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8',
              'nine': '9', 'zero': '0'}


def text_to_digit(s):
    parts = s.split()
    return int(''.join((LOOKUP[p] for p in parts)))


print(text_to_digit('one two two five'))
```

output

```
1225
```

And an ugly 1 liner :-)

```
print(int(''.join(LOOKUP[x] for x in 'one two two five'.split())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
def text_to_digit(s):
    number=''
    d={'one':'1', 'two':'2', 'three':'3', 'four': '4', 'five':'5', 'six':'6', 'seven':'7', 'eight':'8', 'nine':'9', 'zero':'0'}
    for i in s.split():        
        number=number+d[i]    
            
    return int(number)
print(text_to_digit('one two two five'))
```

```
1225
```